# How to set disabled except next week using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker jquery. I would like to add an enable or disable setting so that I can only select the next week based on today . The function I wanted was not found after searching for several days, so I had to post a question. thank you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var next_week = new Date();
    next_week.setDate(today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()));
    var next_weekend = new Date();
    next_weekend.setDate(next_week.getDate()+6);
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: next_week, maxDate: next_weekend });
  } );
  
  // For specific Dates
  /* $( function() {
    var today = new Date("09/15/2021");
    var next_week = new Date("09/15/2021");
    next_week.setDate(today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()));
    var next_weekend = new Date("09/15/2021");
    next_weekend.setDate(next_week.getDate()+6);
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: next_week, maxDate: next_weekend });
  } ); */
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

You can use `min-max` to set the weeks as follows:

```
$( function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var next_week = new Date();
    next_week.setDate(today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()));
    var next_weekend = new Date();
    next_weekend.setDate(next_week.getDate()+6);
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: next_week, maxDate: next_weekend });
  } );
```

Also, you can update the same function for specific dates as follow:

```
$( function() {
    var today = new Date("09/15/2021");
    var next_week = new Date("09/15/2021");
    next_week.setDate(today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()));
    var next_weekend = new Date("09/15/2021");
    next_weekend.setDate(next_week.getDate()+6);
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: next_week, maxDate: next_weekend });
  } );
```

Or If you want to use a date range, the Following snippet works with the date range.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
  var today = new Date();
    var next_week = new Date();
    next_week.setDate(today.getDate()+(7-today.getDay()));
    var next_weekend = new Date();
    next_weekend.setDate(next_week.getDate()+6);
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
         minDate: next_week, 
         maxDate: next_weekend
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        minDate: next_week, 
        maxDate: next_weekend
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

For reference [JQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)